# Embedded Linux board with NFS boot and SSH

Tags: linux, nfs, openssh, embedded-linux

We have a BeagleBone Black-based embedded Linux board. It has eMMC and I have setup for NFS boot also.

When I am booting the board from eMMC, I am able to connect board through SSH but when I am booting board from NFS I get message "**Connection refused**". After looking into NFS root file system, I found that it doesn't have SSH daemon, so I am thinking of adding OpenSSH into NFS root file system.

As per my little understanding of SSH and NFS, SSH on the board uses port 22 and NFS on the board uses 1110 (UDP) and 2049 (TCP). I am using USB2Ethernet Adapter from Board to PC, so there is only one connection from PC to board. In this situation, will SSH and NFS work together or do I have to make some different arrangement ?

Any suggestions/pointers/hint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install an ssh server (OpenSSH or Dropbear) on your NFS rootfs it should work just fine. You do not need more than one Ethernet ports if that is what you mean. SSH and NFS will establish different TCP (and/or UDP in the case of NFS) connections over the same Ethernet interface.

Comment: could finally cross compile it, add it as part of nfsboot and it works like a charm :) Thank you for reply.